# What is the Ansible vault password file format?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I've been searching all over but there's not much on what
should the Ansible vault password file look like.

For example I would like to do:

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=./pwdfile ansible-vault edit secrets.yml
```

But have no idea what format `./pwdfile` should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of a Ansible vault password file should contain **only** the password for the Ansible vault.

Somewhat vaguely described in the official documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#setting-a-default-password-source

That is if you do:

```
$ ansible-vault create secrets.yml
New Vault password: 1234
Confirm New Vault password: 1234
```

Then you can create a password file `pwdfile` with the contents:

```
1234
```

And invoke `ansible-vault edit` like:

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=./pwdfile ansible-vault edit secrets.yml
```

Note you can also pass `--vault-password-file` or `--vault-id` instead of setting the environment variable as described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE

Most of how to use the Ansible vault is described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html

Comment: Note that if the file is executable, ansible will execute it. The script contained in that file should output the password to stdout and ansible will use it. The `community.general` collection has [several examples](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/scripts/vault)

Comment: I can't get to that page, @Zeitounator, but for anyone wondering like I was, just "echo 12345" won't work, you'll need an actual hashbang at the beginning, like a "!#/bin/bash" on the top line.